# Get the closest & highest id using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two lists one for products to select and the other for the selected products
i want to be able to return the selected product to its original place.

I kinda solve it in the following format **but the issue is it might be hundreds of products**

```js
$(document).on('click', "#remove_product", function () {
    var product = $(this).parents("li"),
        found = false;
    $('.products_list li').each(function() {
        if(this.id > product.attr('id') && !found ){
            product.clone().insertBefore(this); 
            found = true;
        }
    });
    if(!found) product.clone().append(".products_list");
    product.remove();
})
```

```css
.products_list button{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="products_list">
  <li id="1">Content 1</li>
  <li id="2">Content 2</li>
  <li id="4">Content 4</li>
  <li id="5">Content 5</li>
</ul>

<hr>

<ul class="selected_products">

  <li id="3">
    Content 3
    <button id="remove_product">remove product</button>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**Any better solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve your goal would be to create a function which sorts the `li` elements within the `ul` based on their `id`. You can then call this function whenever an update is made to the `li`.

The function can also be made generic enough to work for both `ul` containers, when adding/removing an item from each.

Note in the example below that I added the `button` element to each `li` by default, as per your pattern of hiding them through CSS for the initial list. I also changed the `id` on the button to a `class`, as `id` need to be unique.

With that said, try this:

```js
let $productsList = $('.products_list');
let $selectedList = $('.selected_products');
let sortProductsInContainer = $container => $container.find('li').sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1).appendTo($container);

// add product to selected list
$productsList.on('click', 'li', e => {
  $(e.target).closest('li').appendTo($selectedList);
  sortProductsInContainer($selectedList);
});

// remove product from selected list
$selectedList.on('click', ".remove_product", e => {
  $(e.target).closest("li").appendTo($productsList);
  sortProductsInContainer($productsList);
})
```

```css
.products_list button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="products_list">
  <li id="1">Content 1 <button class="remove_product">remove product</button></li>
  <li id="2">Content 2 <button class="remove_product">remove product</button></li>
  <li id="4">Content 4 <button class="remove_product">remove product</button></li>
  <li id="5">Content 5 <button class="remove_product">remove product</button></li>
</ul>

<hr>

<ul class="selected_products">
  <li id="3">Content 3 <button class="remove_product">remove product</button></li>
</ul>
```